# Powerbuilder get selected value from a dropdown list

Tags: list, dropdown, powerbuilder, getvalue

How can I get the value I've selected in a dropdown list?

I've tried something like this but it won't work, ls_est_an is null:

```
ll_row = dw_est_an.rowcount()
dw_est_an.GetChild( "est_an" , dddw )
ls_est_an = dw_est_an.object.est_an[ll_row]
```

Comment: Do you mean a dropdownlistbox or a dropdowndatawindow?

Comment: Dropdowndatawindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the GetSelectedRow method on the datawindow child.

In your example you are getting the value of 'est_an' for the last row in the datawindow 'dw_est_an'.

To get the value of the selected row in the dropdown datawindow you can use
something like:

```
long ll_dddwrow
string ls_val
ll_dddwrow = dddw.getselectedrow(0)
IF ll_dddwrow > 0 THEN
   ls_val = dddw.getitemstring(ll_dddwrow, 'columnname')
END IF
```

This assumes whatever column in the dropdowndatawindow object is of type string.